# Checklist with multiple conditions from a json in ng-if

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a Json file with a lot of items from a checklist and each one have multiple conditions to be displayed. Those conditions depends on other variables on the code that the user will set while using the app, so every item should be displayed or not based on that. Here is the html:

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in checkList" class="{{item.isCritic}}" ng-if="item.conditions">
              <td uib-tooltip-html="{{item.tip}}" tooltip-placement="top" tooltip-trigger="'mouseenter'"><img ng-src="{{item.url}}" alt="{{item.text}}" ng-click="checkImage();"><span class="info checklistInfo" ng-bind-html="item.text"></span></td>
            </tr>
```

The Json:

```
[  {
"id": 1,
"url": "img/checkList/1.png",
"isCritic": "checkListCritico",
"checked": "false",
"text": "text1",
"tip": "_",
"conditions":"vm.conditionA=='NOTEBOOK'"  },{
"id": 2,
"url": "img/checkList/2.png",
"isCritic": "checkListCritico",
"checked": "false",
"text": "text2",
"tip": "_",
"conditions":"vm.conditionA=='NOTEBOOK' && (vm.conditionB=='HP' || vm.conditionB=='Sony' || vm.conditionA=='AllInOne' || vm.conditionB=='dell' || vm.conditionB=='LG' || vm.conditionB=='Samsung')"  },  {
"id": 3,
"url": "img/checkList/3.png",
"isCritic": "checkListCritico",
"checked": "false",
"text": "text3",
"tip": "_",
"conditions":"vm.conditionA=='DESKTOP' && (vm.conditionC=='MOUSE')"  }]
```

I've tried a lot but can't make the ng-if work with the conditions in the Json file, is there any way to do that?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ng-if` will evaluate to `true` since it has a non-empty string if you need to validate this condition you need to evaluate it before passing it to `ng-if` and return `true` or `false` to do that you can use `eval(stringCondtion)`

```
$scope.isVisible = function (stringCondtion) {
    return eval(stringCondtion);
}
```

`stringCondtion` should return from JSON in the same way you write it in the controller as it will run in controller scope.